# Dividing a page into two vertical and identical sections with border

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I'm currently trying to divide a page into two identical and vertical sections with one border on either side. The problem is that I have two sections with width:49vw; and the size of the border is 1vw which equals to 100vw but the sections jumps underneath one another instead of being inline. I have set up a JSFiddle so its easier to show. Here's the code that goes with the JSFiddle.

```css
.section1{
    background-color:#11181e;
    width:49vw;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    border-right: 1vw solid #F5E5D6; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.section2{
    background-color:#f1c40f;
    width:49vw;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    border-left: 1vw solid #000;  
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!--SECTION 1-->
    <div class="section1">
        <p>2D</p>
    </div>
<!--SECTION 2-->
    <div class="section2">
        <p>3D</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/VfTYs/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `width: 50%;` and `box-sizing: border-box` on `.section1` and `.section2`.

```css
body{
 color:#fff;
 font-size:100pt;
}
.section1{
 background-color:#11181e;
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 height:100vh;
 border-right: 1vw solid #F5E5D6; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
}
.section2{
 background-color:#f1c40f;
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
2d
</div>
<div class="section2">
3d
</div>
```

Comment: I also removed the black border on `.section2`.

Comment: No problem, good luck on your project! If I answered your question, mind throwing me the green check mark?